# Can I fetch places within specific coordinate position with Google API

Tags: swift, google-places-api, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm trying to fetch places via coordinate.

In Google Place API Support Similar features..but I just want fetch place objects like placeLikelihoodList.

Anyone knows about this?

I'm making my own function "getCurrentPlace"

It returned placeLikelihoodList but I want fetch placeLikelihoodList within specific coordinate.

```
func reverseGeocodeCoordinate(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {

        //Create Lat/Lon
        let geocoder = GMSGeocoder()



        //get Location Address via LatLon
        geocoder.reverseGeocodeCoordinate(coordinate) { response, error in


            self.addressLbl.unlock()

            self.placeCollectionView.reloadData()

            if let address = response?.firstResult() {

                if let lines = address.lines{


                    if (lines.count > 0) {

                        self.addressLbl.text = lines.joined(separator: "\n")






                        self.getCurrentPlace()

                                 self.addressButton.setTitle(lines[0], forState: .Normal)


                        self.updateMapPadding()




                    }
                }

                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {

                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

                }
            }
        }
    }


 func getNearByPlaces(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D){


        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude)
        let northEast = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: center.latitude + 0.001, longitude: center.longitude + 0.001)
        let southWest = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: center.latitude - 0.001, longitude: center.longitude - 0.001)
        let viewport = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: northEast, coordinate: southWest)
        let config = GMSPlacePickerConfig(viewport: viewport)
        let placePicker = GMSPlacePicker(config: config)

        placePicker.pickPlace(callback: {(place, error) -> Void in
            if let error = error {
                print("Pick Place error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }

            if place != nil {
//                self.nameLabel.text = place.name
//                self.addressLabel.text = place.formattedAddress?.components(separatedBy: ", ")
//                    .joined(separator: "\n")
                print("nearBy")
//                print(place.name)
////                print(place.formattedAddress?.components(separatedBy: ", ")
//                    .joined(separator: "\n"))


            } else {
//                self.nameLabel.text = "No place selected"
//                self.addressLabel.text = ""

                print("No place selected")
            }
        })

    }
```

func getCurrentPlace(){

```
    placesClient.currentPlace(callback: { (placeLikelihoodList, error) -> Void in
        if let error = error {
            print("Pick Place error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }

        if let placeLikelihoodList = placeLikelihoodList {


            for likelihood in placeLikelihoodList.likelihoods {

                let nearByPlace = PlaceCard()

                let place = likelihood.place

                nearByPlace.name = place.name
                nearByPlace.id = place.placeID
                nearByPlace.detail = place.formattedAddress

                self.neayByPlaces.append(nearByPlace)
                self.placeCollectionView.reloadData()


                print("==============================================\(placeLikelihoodList.likelihoods.count)")
                print("Current Place name \(place.name) at likelihood \(likelihood.likelihood)")
                print("Current Place address \(place.formattedAddress)")
                print("Current Place attributions \(place.attributions)")
                print("Current PlaceID \(place.placeID)")



            }
        }
    })
}
```